# Fire Elemental vs. Stone Golem

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The Monster Manual (page 125) says for the Fire Elemental under Touch:

> [...] If the target is a creature or a flammable object, it ignites. [...]

The Stone Golem on page 170 is a creature and does not have immunity or resistance to fire. However, stone isn't very flammable.

**Does the Stone Golem ignite if hit by a Fire Elemental?**

Context: We had a short discussion during our last game session. GM ruled that the Golem ignites but a player disagreed, because (most) stone doesn't burn.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### The golem ignites.

First, there's the rules perspective. As you pointed out, the Fire Elemental ignites creatures and flammable objects. The Stone Golem is a creature. Therefore it ignites.

Second there's the in-fiction perspective, which is what the player was challenging. The Stone Golem is a lump of rock(s) animated by magic, but the Fire Elemental is literally *the essence of fire itself*. If it wants to burn something, then by golly that thing is going to burn. The Fire Elemental is essentially putting a sort of clinging magical fire onto the golem.

Alternately it may be the case that it's the magic that *animates* the golem that's being burned. As vaxquis pointed out in a comment, even creatures that are **completely immune** to fire are ignited by the Fire Elemental's touch, they just don't take any *damage* from it. The fact that the Stone Golem doesn't even have resistance to fire, much less immunity, suggests that *something* about it burns just fine.

Answer (score 20):

## The Golem would ignite

> [...] If the target is a creature **or** a flammable object, it ignites. [...]

A Golem is a creature (specifically a construct).

So it will ignite. The flammable question only becomes relevant if you are talking about objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That was exactly the GMs view on that matter. However, I will accept the answer of @ObliviousSage since it addresses the underlying immersion problem (which wasn't obvious for me).